# how to read the values of Arraylist from Map in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

I am not able to read the values of Arraylist from MAP from the below code please suggest what should do.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<String,List<CommentModel>> results) {
        super.onPostExecute(results);

        results.get(0).get(commentModelList);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Helloji" + results, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

and values added to Map i think put the values in Map in the right ways. please suggest what to do as i am stuck here .

```
   String line = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            buffer.append(line);
            String result = buffer.toString();
            JSONArray jsondata = new JSONArray(result);
            commentModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            commentModelList_child = new ArrayList<>();
            map =new HashMap();

            for(int i=0;i<=jsondata.length();i++){

                CommentModel cmnmodel = new CommentModel();

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsondata.getJSONObject(i);

                int id= jsonObject.getInt("id");
                String content = jsonObject.getString("content");

                    cmnmodel.setContent(content);
                    cmnmodel.setId(id);
                commentModelList.add(cmnmodel);
                commentModelList_child.add(cmnmodel);

                map.put("commentModelList",commentModelList);
                map.put("commentModelList_child",commentModelList_child);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key of your `Map` is `String` not `Integer`.

```
results.get(0).get(commentModelList);
```

Instead of passing Integer as a key, use String as a key, in return you will get List.

```
List<CommentModel> comments = results.get("value_of_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it backwards.

```
results.get(commentModelList).get(0);
```